# Creating array from Excel and adding missing data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, missing-data

I am reading an excel file with columns Date, Hour and Value. Dates are ranged from 07-15-2014 to 07-15-2016. I do not have some hours of those days in my excel file. For example, data starts from 07-15-2014 at 13:00, but so first 13 hours are missing. Likewise, for example in some days there are 23 hours logged in excel, but the other hour is missing.

What I am trying to do is, I will create an `numpy array` with shape `[# of days, 24, 3]` which will have `NaN` if corresponding date and hour does not exist in `xlsx` file.

Here is what I have done:

```
def read_XT(path):
    # first row is header
    df = pd.read_excel(in_path +'.xlsx',skiprows=1)

    origin= datetime.strptime(df[u'DATE'][0]+' '+'00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
    final = datetime.strptime(df[u'DATE'].iloc[-1]+' '+'00:00:00', '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')

    # find number of days
    ndays = (final-origin).days+1

    # initialize array with size and NaN values
    XT = np.ndarray(shape = (ndays,24,3), dtype="S10")
    XT[:, :, :] = np.nan

    for idx in range(df.shape[0]):
        day,hour = df[u'DATE'][idx],df[u'HOUR'][idx]

        # strip time
        dt = datetime.strptime(day+' '+hour, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S')
        # find difference from the first timestamp
        dftime = dt-origin
        hour_idx = int(dftime.total_seconds()/(60*60))%24
        day_idx = dftime.days

        # put corresponding value to day and index
        XT[day_idx,hour_idx,:] = [day, hour, df[u'VALUE'].iloc[idx]]

    return XT
```

My array's first element (which should include the first values of first day's hours) looks like this:

```
[['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['nan' 'nan' 'nan']
  ['15-07-2014' '13:00:00' '28094.034']
  ['15-07-2014' '14:00:00' '28095.79']
  ['15-07-2014' '15:00:00' '28097.541']
  ['15-07-2014' '16:00:00' '28099.26']
  ['15-07-2014' '17:00:00' '28101.022']
  ['15-07-2014' '18:00:00' '28102.751']
  ['15-07-2014' '19:00:00' '28104.428']
  ['15-07-2014' '20:00:00' '28106.118']
  ['15-07-2014' '21:00:00' '28107.877']
  ['15-07-2014' '22:00:00' '28109.625']
  ['15-07-2014' '23:00:00' '28111.523']]
```

But I want to have `['15-07-2014' '00:00' 'nan']`, `['15-07-2014' '01:00' 'nan']` instead of `['nan' 'nan' 'nan']` in first hour and so on.

Should I iterate over the array and put the date and hour by hand if the value is missing? Or is there an easier solution for my problem?

Comment: I wouldn't store all the dates and times in the array. You can just store the actual data in a `(# of days, 24)` array. And return the start date in a seperate variable.